# Android app builds, but crashes in emulator

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity

My app keeps crashing and I have no idea what is causing this. The app builds, but keeps crashing in the emulator.

I tried to change `MainActivity`, but still it's not working.

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btLogout;
EditText etName, etPSN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etPSN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPSN);

    btLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogout);
    btLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btLogout:

            break;
        default : break;
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Name"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="PSN"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPSN"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btLogout"
    android:text="Logout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:capitalize="characters" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: update your logcat when the app crash

Comment: What _exactly_ happens when it crashes?  What does the stack trace tell you?  What did you change, and how did that affect the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must using 
 `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Instead

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

Comment: Thanks man. I just found out lol while debugging. Thanks for the help tho